# Where is download buffer is getting saved in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, download, buffer

Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Click on download link.
2. You will be prompted to choose where you want to save the file.
3. Do not click on save/cancel until you see entire green bar completed.
4. The green bar is completed. Leave save window open.

**Shown in the picture below:**
[image]

I have already checked in `temp` folder (Windows+R > type %temp% > Enter).

Where is this download getting saved?

**Edit:**

1. Yes, the file is getting saved somewhere. I can say that because it shows the download progress from small green to maximum green to no green at all.
2. Once the green bar is over and I click save I get the file available instantly.
3. It happens in Firefox, Chrome both.

Comment: Hey @downvoter could you please let me know why you downvoted? Is it not formatted properly, wrong forum etc ?

Comment: Seems you are not the downvoter 'cause you asked right questions. Let me put these in question description. \m/

Comment: Why is this important? You’ve seen that browsers do stage your download to a temporary area first. So what are you trying to accomplish? Obviously each browser is gong to be different, and a likely place they save the temp file is in each browser’s temporary internet files.

Comment: You could always use ProcMon to find out. However, it’s most likely held in RAM. // And to all questioning this: Yes, both Firefox and Chrome start downloading before you specified a filename. It’s a great idea, too.